# Problem creating a circular buffer in shared memory using Boost

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess, circular-buffer

I am trying to create a circular buffer in shared memory using Boost `circular_buffer` and Interprocess libraries. I compiled and ran the the example given in the [Interprocess documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) for creating a vector in shared memory with no problem. However, when I modify it to use the Boost circular_buffer as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
    const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
    MyCircBuffer  *myCircBuf  = segment.construct<MyCircBuffer>("MyCircBuffer")(alloc_inst);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error (caused by `segment.construct()`). Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is it because `circular_buffer` is not one of the containers listed in `/boost/interprocess/containers`, i.e. it's not compatible with Interprocess?

Thanks,

C

Comment: can you provide the compilation error message?

Comment: Please post the error list and compiler...

Comment: Sorry for not giving all the details. The error I get is 
/usr/local/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:2127: error: cannot convert ‘boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<int>’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’
I'm using gcc v4.2.1 on MAc OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question on the boost user forum and the solution that was suggested was to use -DBOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG or -DNDEBUG flags, since `circular_buffer` relies on raw pointers for debug support.

Any other suggestions?